# How do I make a thread wait for a variable to change?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I want the function `foo()` to wait for an array to be updated. The struct `data` contains the arguments to the `foo()` method. I attach `foo()` to a thread and I have a while loop in the `foo()` function that checks for when `updated` is `1` (which means the `main()` function changed the array. It's supposed to print the array when that happens.

This doesn't print anything; the program just stalls forever. I'm not too familiar with threading so I don't know if this is the right way to do this.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data {
    int array[5];
    int updated;
};

pthread_cond_t cv;
pthread_mutex_t mp;
pthread_condattr_t cattr;
int ret;

void* foo(void* da) {
    struct data* d = (struct data*)da;
    while (d->updated == 0) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mp);
        if (d->updated == 1) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mp);
            printf("Updated: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                printf("%d ", d->array[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            d->updated = 0;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    void *status;
    struct data temp;
    temp.updated = 0;

    ret = pthread_cond_init(&cv, NULL);
    ret = pthread_cond_init(&cv, &cattr);

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, foo, (void *) &temp);
    int rc = pthread_join(thread, &status);
    if (rc) {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        temp.array[i] *= 2;
    }
    temp.updated = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Edit:

After making the changes recommended in the answers, this is what I have now. It's printing the array, but I want it to detect whenever the array is changed (i.e whenever `updated` is set to true). At the moment `foo` is just acting like a regular non-threaded function.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int array[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};

pthread_cond_t cv;
pthread_mutex_t mp;
int updated = 0;

pthread_cond_t cv2;
pthread_mutex_t mp2;
int donePrinting = 0;

void* foo(void* a) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp);

    int* arr = *(int**)a;
    
    while (1) {
        while (updated == 0)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mp);
        printf("Updated: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        updated = 0;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mp2);
        donePrinting = 1;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cv2); // Signal to main that we are done printing
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp2);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp);
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void changeArray(void) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        array[i] += 2;
    }
    updated = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp);
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread;
    void *status;
    
    pthread_cond_init(&cv, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cv2, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mp, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mp2, NULL);
    
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, foo, &array);
    
    // """"""""""""
    // Change the array

    changeArray();

    // Wait for the second thread to finish printing

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp2);
    while (!donePrinting)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv2, &mp2);
    changeArray();
    donePrinting = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp2);
return 0;
    // Change the array again
    

    // Wait for the second thread to finish printing
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp2);
    while (!donePrinting)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv2, &mp2);
    donePrinting = 0;
    changeArray();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp2);

    // """"""""""""""""
    
    int rc = pthread_join(thread, &status);
    if (rc) {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Where is cattr initialized?

Comment: @stark `ret = pthread_cond_init(&cv, &cattr);`

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_condattr_init.3p.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the lines

```
ret = pthread_cond_init(&cv, NULL);
ret = pthread_cond_init(&cv, &cattr);
```

are wrong. It does not make sense to call `pthread_cond_init` twice on the same condition variable `cv`. Also, if you use `cattr`, you should initialize it first before passing it to `pthread_cond_init`. If you want to use default condition variable attributes instead, then you should simply pass `NULL` instead of `&cattr`. You probably want to do the latter. In that case, you should simply delete the second line and also delete the declaration of `cattr`.

Also, you must initialize the mutex `mp` before using it, using [`pthread_mutex_init`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_destroy.3p.html).

The line

```
int rc = pthread_join(thread, &status);
```

will cause the main thread to wait until the second thread has finished. However, this will never happen, because the line

```
temp.updated = 1;
```

which the second thread is waiting for, occurs later in the main thread. Therefore, you should move

```
int rc = pthread_join(thread, &status);
```

after the line:

```
temp.updated = 1;
```

Also, you should add a call to [`pthread_cond_signal`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_signal.3p.html) after the line

```
temp.updated = 1;
```

but before the line

```
int rc = pthread_join(thread, &status);
```

so that the second thread gets gets notified that it should check the variable again.

Also, in the second thread, the line

```
while (d->updated == 0) {
```

is wrong, because you are not holding the mutex when you execute that line. This causes undefined behavior (due to a race condition on the shared variable).

Therefore, if you want to keep the `d->updated == 0` loop condition, then you must move the line

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mp);
```

before the line:

```
while (d->updated == 0) {
```

This means that you will have two restructure your loops, because the position of `pthread_mutex_unlock` must also be in the right place.

However, I doubt that it is appropriate that you keep the `d->updated == 0` loop condition. If that it supposed to be an infinite loop, then you can write `for (;;)` or `while ( 1 )` instead, so that you don't have the problem of accessing a shared variable in the loop condition.

---

Regarding your updated code, I believe this is a working version of the program, which does everything that you want:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int array[5] = {0};

pthread_cond_t cv;
pthread_mutex_t mp;
int updated = 0;
int terminate = 0;

pthread_cond_t cv2;
pthread_mutex_t mp2;
int donePrinting = 0;

void* foo(void* a) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp);

    int* arr = a;
    
    while ( 1 ) {
        while ( updated == 0 && terminate == 0 )
            pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mp);

        if ( terminate )
            break;

        printf("Updated: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
            fflush( stdout );
        }
        printf("\n");
        fflush( stdout );
        updated = 0;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mp2);
        donePrinting = 1;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cv2); // Signal to main that we are done printing
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp2);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp);
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void changeArray(void) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        array[i] += 2;
    }
    updated = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp);
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread;
    void *status;
    
    pthread_cond_init(&cv, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cv2, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mp, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mp2, NULL);
    
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, foo, (void*)&array);
    
    // """"""""""""
    // Change the array

    changeArray();

    // Wait for the second thread to finish printing
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp2);
    while (!donePrinting)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv2, &mp2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp2);

    //reset donePrinting
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp2);
    donePrinting = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp2);

    // Change the array again
    changeArray();

    // Wait for the second thread to finish printing
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp2);
    while (!donePrinting)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv2, &mp2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp2);

    //reset doneprinting
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp2);
    donePrinting = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp2);

    // Change the array a third time
    changeArray();

    // """"""""""""""""

    // Wait for the second thread to finish printing
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp2);
    while (!donePrinting)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv2, &mp2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp2);

    //send terminate request
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mp);
    terminate = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mp);
    
    int rc = pthread_join(thread, &status);
    if (rc) {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I changed the program so that the main thread sends a termination request to the second thread, when processing has finished and there is nothing left to send.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242743/discussion-on-answer-by-andreas-wenzel-how-do-i-make-a-thread-wait-for-a-variabl).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `pthread_cond_signal` at a certain point in this program.

Comment: Should I do it right after I update the array?

Comment: There is a specific place where it goes, and you should be able to figure out where that is with the information you have.

Comment: I updated my code (as you can see in my post) but the program still doesn't work. It prints the latest change made to the array, but I want the `foo()` thread to detect multiple changes whenever they occur.

Comment: "Whenever they occur" is only possible by using special hardware features that can only monitor one or two machine words at a time, not an entire array. "Every time someone calls `pthread_cond_signal`" is easily possible, but requires a loop in your thread procedure.